# Update Spring Embedded Entity throws Stack Overflow Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently trying to update a Record which contains an Embedded Entity. When trying this, i am getting the following Error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

When i create the Entity, everything is working fine.

This is what i have right now:

My Main Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Account")
@Table(name = "account")
@DynamicUpdate
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account extends Auditable<String> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String id;
    @Column(
            name = "Description",
            length = 512)
    private String description;
    @Column(
            name = "AnnualRevenue",
            length = 18)
    private String annualRevenue;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides(value = {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name = "billingAddressCity")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "country", column = @Column(name = "billingAddressCountry")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "latitude", column = @Column(name = "billingAddressLatitude")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "longitude", column = @Column(name = "billingAddressLongitude")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "postalCode", column = @Column(name = "billingAddressPostalCode")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "state", column = @Column(name = "billingAddressState")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "street", column = @Column(name = "billingAddressStreet"))
    })
    private Address billingAddress;
    @Column(name = "Industry")
    private String industry;
    @Column(name = "IsDeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
    @Column(
            name = "Employees",
            length = 8
    )
    private int employees;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "Type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "Website")
    private String website;
    @OneToMany(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.ALL
            }
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("account")
    private final List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Here, i am using an Embedded Entity for the Address which looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address {

    private String city;
    private String country;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private String postalCode;
    private String state;
    private String street;

}
```

Furthermore, the Account can have multiple Contacts which is is defined like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Contact")
@Table(name = "contact")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude
public class Contact extends Auditable<String> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "Department")
    private String department;
    @Column(
            name = "Email"
    )
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Salutation")
    private String salutation;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "accountId",
            nullable = false,
            referencedColumnName = "Id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "AccountContactFK"
            )
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("contacts")
    private Account account;

}
```

For the Account, i am using the DTO Principle to map the Fields which looks like this:

DTO for Creation:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AccountCreationDTO {

    private String description;
    private String annualRevenue;
    private Address billingAddress;
    private String industry;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    private int employees;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String type;
    private String website;

}
```

DTO for Update:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AccountUpdateDTO {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private String annualRevenue;
    @Embedded
    private Address billingAddress;
    private String industry;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    private int employees;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String type;
    private String website;

}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AccountController {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Account createObject(@RequestBody @DTO(AccountCreationDTO.class) Account account) {
        //account.setBillingAddress(account.getBillingAddress());
        //this.addressRepository.save(account.getBillingAddress());
        Account createdAccount = this.accountRepository.saveAndFlush(account);
        log.info("Created Account: {}", createdAccount);
        return createdAccount;
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/updateAcc")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> updateAccount(@DTO(AccountUpdateDTO.class) Account account) {
        Account updatedAccount = this.accountRepository.saveAndFlush(account);
        log.info("Updated Account: {}", updatedAccount);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(updatedAccount);
    }

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the embedded entity, but your bi-directional relationship between `Account` and `Contract`. Jackson tries to create the json for `Account` which has  collection of `Contact` instances, which has a reference to `Account`, which has a collection of `Contact` instances, which have a reference to `Account`, which have .... You probably get the point. You have to mark the `Account` in `Context` as a `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonBackReference` so it will be ignored instead of leading to a cyclic JSON being generated (this question has been answered before multiple times BTW).

Comment: I tried both of your Solutions but i still get the same Error as before.

Comment: Then you probably didn't properly rebuild or didn't use the proper annotation (or in the wrong location). I also notice some custom annotation with probably some custom code to handle those (interested as well). And please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: This is the full Stacktrace i get.

Comment: I have adjusted my Entities a little bit to avoid the Recursion. But i am still getting the same Error as bevore.

Comment: You haven't done as I said... I said to use `@JsonIgnore` **not** to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` ... You should place `@JsonIgnore` on the `Account` field in the `Contact`.

Comment: When i use @JsonIgnore on the Account Field in the Contact Entity it still throws the exact same Error.

Comment: Then I doubt this is the code in use and there is something that you aren't telling us. For starters (as asked before) include the **full stacktrace** in the question. I really doubt that that is the full stacktrace in the logging (it might be on the web response but not your logfile). Another thing is you are apparently a fan of Lombok, I wonder do you use something to generate a toString etc. in your code...